# Density of finite linear combinations of homogeneous harmonic polynomials in $L^p$ on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

I was reading a paper on harmonic analysis on spheres, and there is a result about the $L^2$ spectral decompositions on spheres. A key result is as follows:

$\textbf{Theorem}:$ The collection of finite linear combinations of homogeneous harmonic polynomials restricted to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}).$

My question, is as follows: Is this result true for $L^p,~p>2?$ I initially thought the answer was no, and it was related to orthogonality holding in $L^2$ but not $L^p,~p>2$, but now I am not sure.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, it is true.   In fact it is true in any   Sobolev or Holder norm, and in fact it is true for any compact Riemann manifold,  where the role of harmonic polynomials is played by the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide a link where I can read more about this?

Comment: The proof is not hard if you are  familiar with the basics  of the theory of elliptic operators,  but  very difficult to understand otherwise. In any case,  check section 10.4.2 of http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf